# Dust buildup and vent airflow - Should my vents be completely open?

Tags: vent, air, dust

The room that I am in is particularly dusty compared to all the other rooms since I'm in it most of the time and it's very small with lots of stuff inside.

I do my best to dust every surface but it comes back at a fast and regular rate.

So far I've tried to clean my air filters and dusted off the vents and it seemed to help a bit, but still lots of dust. I can't always keep the door open because it's too loud when I'm doing work with my family at home.

I was thinking that if I restrict the vents a bit there would be less air flow but less dust would come in, so I did that.

However, I realized that it might be doing the opposite but I'm not sure.

**Should I keep my vents open completely or partially closed? Considering the affect on dust build up and air quality and what is the best option?**

Comment: I think you shall consider hiring a vent cleaning company to get rid of the dust accumulated over the years. If the partially opened/closed vent can cool down your place without running up the utility bill, and there is a noticeable reduction in dust, why not continue the way it is?!

Comment: I see, thanks I'll try to find it.

I live in an apartment and live with my parents who are stingy about money so I don't make the decisions to hire cleaning companies. All we get from the apartment service is someone who comes annually to check things out/replace air filters.

I'm not worried about the temperature of the room particularly but the air flow if my room is closed. 

I partially closed the vent in my room because I thought it would reduce the amount of dust coming through but I wasn't sure if it's the opposite. For now should I leave it partially open or open it completely?

Comment: I'll try to measure the dust situation by keeping the vent fully open for a stretch of two weeks, and fully closed for another two, and cunting the frequency of needing cleaning and the amount of dust collected (keep the dust in a garbage bag so quantifiable). It is not a scientific way but can provide you a clue to make your decision.

Comment: Another way is to add a vent filter that is available from the hardware store. It can block out large particles yet allow airflow. However, you might need to change it frequently, therefore, an added cost.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions, I don't really have that much dust coming through it's just annoying to have to wipe the small amount that surfaces on my laptop everyday and I was wondering how opening the vent partially versus completely might affect how much dust & oxygen goes into my room.

Answer (score 1):

It's never a good idea to close vents. You need the air circulating so keep them open.

Get an inexpensive filter from your home store and cut a piece from it the size of your vent. Install it inside the vent register or tape it over the register and see if it cuts down on the dust.

Comment: Not even partially? 
Opening the vent completely = more air flow and less dust or more air flow and more dust?
Do you believe how open the vent is affects the oxygen in the room when the door is closed?

Comment: You could partially close it but if you try the added filter, you'll reduce air flow a bit.